# xcode 3.2 + iPhoneOS 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode

Anybody have any luck with building for iPhoneOS 2.2.1 with snow leopard / xcode 3.2?  I tried installing the packages from the xcode dmg (it comes with them), but now I can't seem to get around the "Stdarg.h: No such file or directory" problems.  This only happens when I build for the simulator, not when I build for the device.

Anybody solve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 3.2 no longer includes the libraries for the 2.x simulator; you can only build against the device (as you've found out).

Comment: I copied iPhoneSimulator2.2.1.sdk and iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk from where the xcode3.2 installer puts them after installing those packages (in /Platforms/blahblah) to /Developer/Platforms/etc.  This made those platforms show up in xcode.  Is this different than installing the libraries for the 2.x simulator?  Is there a way to install the libraries for the 2.x simulator?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to get the 2.x sim running under Snow Leopard. It may be possible with an extraordinary amount of hacking, but almost certainly more work than switching back to Leopard (my solution) for debugging.